# walk on slope or uneven ground

Tags: animation, physics

How to create a human walking nicely on slope or uneven ground? I used mocap and IK. I think I need to add physics in the animation. How to let the human know he is walking on a slope and change his feet....?

Comment: Did you capture the action of walking up a slope?

Comment: Yes. I used mocap. @RobinBetts